# How to perform search on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, search, find, tuples

I have a list of tuples. For example, I have the following:

```
a=[('jamy', 'k'), ('Park', 'h'), ('kick', 'p'), ('an', 'o'),('an',
'o'),('an', 'o'),('an', 'r'), ('car', 'k'), ('rock', 'h'), ('pig',
'p')]
```

And another list,

```
b = ['k','h','p']
```

I would like to find the pattern in list b from second tuple element of list a.

Here in the above example the output should return,

```
[('jamy','Park','kick'),('car','rock','pig')]
```

Can someone help me to achieve my goals?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: What if the list were `a=[('jamy', 'k'), ('Park', 'h'), ('kick', 'p'), ('an', 'o'),('an', 'o'),('an', 'o'),('an', 'r'), ('rock', 'h'), ('pig', 'p')]` whitout the 'car' tuple. Should the output be `[('jamy','Park','kick'),('jamy','rock','pig')]` or `[('jamy','Park','kick')]`

Comment: Not sure if this is a requirement, but my code works even if `'k','h','p'` are not consecutive in `a`. As in if the letters in the pairs from `a` are: `khhprgskrfbhevp`, it will match the `khp` from `khhprgsKrfbHevP`, caps indicate which letters are being matched.

Comment: @Vysa Welcome to Stack Overflow, when you think your question has been answered you should selected an *Accepted Answer* by clicking the *V* icon under the upvote and downvote arrows of that answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [(a[x][0], a[x+1][0], a[x+2][0])
                        for x, _ in enumerate(a) 
                                 if a[x][1] == b[0] and 
                                    a[x+1][1] == b[1] and
                                    a[x+2][1] == b[2]]
```

Comment: @oleg thanks, was a quick answer. Maybe op should tell us if b may have variable length or it should refer to a[x][0] to

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the length of `b` is 3, the following code will work even if `a` contains `'k','h','p'` such that they do not always follow each other properly, as in:

```
a=[('test', 'k'), ('jamy', 'k'), ('Park', 'h'), ('kick', 'p'), ('car', 'k'),
('an', 'r'),('rock', 'h'), ('see','k'), ('it','h'),('an', 'o'),('works', 'p')]

b = ['k','h','p']
```

will produce:

```
[('jamy', 'Park', 'kick'), ('see', 'it', 'works')]
```

Code:

```
letters_a = "".join(str(tup[1]) for tup in a)
letters_b = "".join(str(letter) for letter in b)
regex = re.compile(r'(%s)[^%s]*(%s)[^%s]*(%s)' 
                  % (letters_b[0],letters_b[:2],letters_b[1],letters_b,letters_b[2]))
#for this example, the above line translates to:
#regex = re.compile(r'(k)[^kh]*(h)[^khp]*(p)')
match = re.finditer(regex, letters_a)

results=[]
for m in match:
    first,second,third = m.start(1), m.start(2), m.start(3)
    results.append((a[first][0],a[second][0],a[third][0]))

print results
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet.

```
list_of_values = [
    ('jamy', 'k'), ('Park', 'h'), ('kick', 'p'), ('an', 'o'), ('an', 'o'),
    ('an', 'o'), ('an', 'r'), ('car', 'k'), ('rock', 'h'), ('pig', 'p')
]
pattern = ('k','h','p')

# Important part
matches = [
    values for values, keys in (
        zip(*list_of_values[i:i + len(pattern)])
        for i in range(len(list_of_values) - len(pattern) + 1)
    ) if keys == pattern
]

print(matches)
>> [('jamy', 'Park', 'kick'), ('car', 'rock', 'pig')]
```

Comment: @drewk that is because there are no sequential values that match the pattern. The user didn't specify whether random keys should be allowed between the pattern keys but he did specify it was a **pattern**.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [('jamy', 'k'), ('Park', 'h'), ('kick', 'p'),
     ('an', 'o'), ('an', 'o'), ('an', 'o'), ('an', 'r'),
     ('car', 'k'), ('rock', 'h'), ('pig', 'p')]

b = ['k', 'h', 'p']

filtered = [ele for ele in a if ele[1] in b]

def split_list(_list, idx_range):
    _t = []
    _temp = []
    _d = {idx + 1: ele for idx, ele in enumerate(_list)}
    for k in _d:
        if k % idx_range == 0:
            _t.append(_d[k])
            _temp.append(_t)
            _t = []
        else:
            _t.append(_d[k])
    return _temp

_nested = split_list(filtered, len(b))

_l1 = []
for outer in _nested:
    _s = ''
    for inner in outer:
        _s += inner[1]
    _l1.append(_s)

_l2 = [_nested[idx] for idx, ele in enumerate(_l1) if ''.join(b) == ele]

final = []
for ele in _l2:
    tup = [e[0] for e in ele]
    final.append(tuple(tup))

print final
```

Output:

```
[('jamy', 'Park', 'kick'), ('car', 'rock', 'pig')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
a = [
    ('jamy', 'k'), ('Park', 'h'), ('kick', 'p'), ('an', 'o'), ('an', 'o'),
    ('an', 'o'), ('an', 'r'), ('car', 'k'), ('rock', 'h'), ('pig', 'p')
]
b = ('k','h','p')
```

If your goal is to gather groups of tuples from list `a` based the second element occurring in the same order as the sequence in `b` you can do this:

```
result=[]
for sl in [a[i:i+len(b)] for i in range(0,len(a))]:
    if tuple([tp[1] for tp in sl])==b:
        result.append(tuple(tp[0] for tp in sl))

print result        
# [('jamy', 'Park', 'kick'), ('car', 'rock', 'pig')]
```

Comment: This will **not** follow the pattern in all cases! Check for `list_of_values = [("Park", "h"), ("jamy", "k"), ("kick", "p")]` which will produce `[("jamy", "Park", "kick")]` even though they are not in the right order.

Comment: @OdraEncoded: You are inventing that requirement. It is not stated if the order of the pattern list or the list of tuples should determine the order of output. With the `pattern=('k','h','p')` **and** `list_of_values = [("Park", "h"), ("jamy", "k"), ("kick", "p")]` the output of `[("jamy", "Park", "kick")]` seems correct to me.

Comment: They are **both** 'patterns'. Either the order of `('k','h','p')` determines the order of the output or the order of the letters in the tuples. Why do you say that the order of the list `pattern` should not be the order of the output?

Comment: I didn't say that, I said the order values should match the order of the pattern because it is a pattern. You seem more experienced than me when it comes to semantics so I'll take your understanding on what a "pattern" means to be correct, however the question clearly states that the user wants to "find the pattern", if they want to *find* it then the pattern refers to the search algorithm not to the output construction.